# What is the best way to store image in device using Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, blob, sqflite

I was trying to save  gallery image file using image picker. I don't know it's not saving in directory. So I decided to store it in database.

1. How to store image in sqlite database?
2. Image storing as String or Blob or any other type which is better to store image in database?
3. Is there any problem storing in database than local storage?
4. If you prefer local storage, then give me code of picking image using imagepicker and store it in local storage.

Comment: check this post https://medium.com/@himanshuranjan30/using-image-picker-with-flutter-and-storing-it-in-local-storage-too-153f7bc8ee1a